# Azure SQL Database Outbound Transfer Cost

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, powerbi

We are planning to use a Azure database server in EastUS region which has outbound data transfer rate of 0.09$ per GB. We would be inserting around 3GB of data per month in the database and if we need to show some report for 1 year in PowerBI which is hosted in the same region, do we need to pay 0.09*3GB*12months-->3.24$ (neglecting 5GB free data) just for one outbound transfer.

1) If we access the PowerBI report X times, do we need to pay 3.24 multipled by X dollars? And what I understand for outbound transfer is that if we access the data from same region, there is no charge. 
2) If we(client or someone) access the PowerBI report from different region what would be the charge?

Comment: What would be the size of each report?

Comment: For 12 months, it would be 36GB (3GB*12months) size

Comment: Would creating a report require 3GB of data?

Comment: Yes, we would be doing some monitoring of sensor and we need to show the entire data (not just the aggregated data) in the report.

Comment: Have you seen https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/feea9712-8817-40dc-8788-c45703ffb5f2/outbound-data-transfers-from-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse?forum=AzureSQLDataWarehouse and https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/11571870-egress-charges-from-scheduled-refresh-against-sour ?

Comment: Yes ,there is no charge,if the services are in same region

Comment: Is it a live query report or is it a cached dataset in Power BI? If the latter what is the scheduled refresh frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charges are based on where the data is hosted. If your PowerBi app is in the same region as your DB, you should now incur any egress charges.

See the last comment here: http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Pricing-for-Azure-and-Power-BI/td-p/25018

and this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/feea9712-8817-40dc-8788-c45703ffb5f2/outbound-data-transfers-from-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse?forum=AzureSQLDataWarehouse

You will have to pay other costs associated with PowerBi but data egress charges won't be one of them if they're hosted in the same region.